How to draw such a sphere with mesh
I want to recreate a ball with mesh like this, use different style for the front and back.

I tried using MeshShading, but the mesh lines looked too thick, can I draw the mesh smaller?
n = 40; 
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u]  Cos[v], Sin[u]  Sin[v], Cos[u]}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Cyan, Gray]], MeshStyle -> None,
 MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, Automatic}}, 
 Mesh -> {Range[0., Pi, Pi/n], Rest@Range[0., 2 Pi, 2 Pi/n]}, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large
 ]



jj = Flatten@Table[{i, i + .03}, {i, 0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/50}];
kk = Flatten@Table[{i, i + .1}, {i, 0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/50}];
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]}, {u, 0, 
  Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Cyan, Gray]], 
 MeshStyle -> None, 
 MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, Automatic}}, 
 Mesh -> {jj, kk}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large]




Besides of the Mesh method, here we provide a region method.
We construct some holes in the Parameter {u,v}-domain. d is the thickness of the belts (the thickness of the top, bottom,left and right is d/2)
0< d < Min[(xmax - xmin)/ m, (ymax - ymin)/n].

Clear["Global`*"];
{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = {{0, π}, {0, 2  π}};
{m, n} = {19, 17};
d = .3 Min[(xmax - xmin)/ m, (ymax - ymin)/n];
x = (xmax - xmin)/m - d;
y = (ymax - ymin)/n - d;
datax = Accumulate@
   Flatten@Join[{xmin, d/2}, Table[{x, d}, m - 1], {x, d/2}];
regx = MeshRegion[List /@ datax, 
   Line /@ Partition[Range[2, Length@datax], 2, 2]];
datay = Accumulate@
   Flatten@Join[{ymin, d/2}, Table[{y, d}, n - 1], {y, d/2}];
regy = MeshRegion[List /@ datay, 
   Line /@ Partition[Range[2, Length@datay], 2, 2]];
rectangle = 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]];
reg = RegionDifference[rectangle, RegionProduct[regx, regy]]


ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u]Cos[v], Sin[u]Sin[v], Cos[u]}, {u, v} ∈ reg, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Cyan, Gray]], Mesh -> None, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All]



The datax,datay can be set as Mesh.

ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]}, {u, xmin, 
  xmax}, {v, ymin, ymax}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Cyan, Gray]], Mesh -> {datax, datay},
  MeshStyle -> None, 
 MeshShading -> {{None, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All]


test the example by @eldo

Clear["Global`*"];
{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}};
{m, n} = {19, 17};
d = .3 Min[(xmax - xmin)/ m, (ymax - ymin)/n];
x = (xmax - xmin)/m - d;
y = (ymax - ymin)/n - d;
datax = Accumulate@
   Flatten@Join[{xmin, d/2}, Table[{x, d}, m - 1], {x, d/2}];
regx = MeshRegion[List /@ datax, 
   Line /@ Partition[Range[2, Length@datax], 2, 2]];
datay = Accumulate@
   Flatten@Join[{ymin, d/2}, Table[{y, d}, n - 1], {y, d/2}];
regy = MeshRegion[List /@ datay, 
   Line /@ Partition[Range[2, Length@datay], 2, 2]];
rectangle = 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]];
reg = RegionDifference[rectangle, RegionProduct[regx, regy]]
enneper = {u - (u^3/3) + u    v^2, v - (v^3/3) + u^2    v, 
   u^2 - v^2};
plot1 = ParametricPlot3D[enneper, {u, v} \[Element] reg, 
  ImageSize -> Large, Lighting -> "ThreePoint", Mesh -> None, 
  PlotPoints -> 64, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Red, Darker@Green]]]; plot2 = 
 ParametricPlot3D[enneper, {u, -2, 2}, {v, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> Large,
   Lighting -> "ThreePoint", MeshStyle -> None, 
  MeshShading -> {{None, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
  Mesh -> {datax, datay}, PlotPoints -> 64, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Red, Darker@Green]]];
{plot1, plot2}



+1 - Perforated regions like this should be very useful in many cases

Using kglr's answer to Jeener's Flower
Width of the mesh bands
w = 1/3;


Number of mesh bands
n = 25;


mesh = 
  Rescale[#, MinMax @ #, {0, 2 Pi}] & @
    Accumulate[Flatten @ ConstantArray[{1, w}, n]];

ParametricPlot3D[
 {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]},
 {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
 Boxed -> False,
 Axes -> False,
 MeshStyle -> None,
 MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, Automatic}},
 Mesh -> {mesh, Rest @ mesh},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Cyan, Gray]]]


w = 1/10;

n = 5;

mesh = 
  Rescale[#, MinMax @ #, {0, 2 Pi}] & @
    Accumulate[Flatten @ ConstantArray[{1, w}, n]];

ParametricPlot3D[
 {Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]}, 
 {u, 0,  Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
 Boxed -> False,
 Axes -> False,
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint",
 MeshStyle -> None,
 MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, Automatic}},
 Mesh -> {mesh, Rest @ mesh},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotPoints -> 64,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Darker @ Red, Yellow]]]


mesh also functions with more complicated surfaces where normal mesh - instructions would produce ragged borders.
enneper = {u - (u^3/3) + u v^2, v - (v^3/3) + u^2 v, u^2 - v^2};

mesh = 
  Rescale[#, MinMax @ #, {-2, 2}] & @
    Accumulate[Flatten @ ConstantArray[{1, 1/2}, 15]];

ParametricPlot3D[enneper, {u, -2, 2}, {v, -2, 2},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint",
 MeshStyle -> None,
 MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, Automatic}},
 Mesh -> {mesh, Rest @ mesh},
 PlotPoints -> 64,
 PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Red, Darker @ Green]]]


